# How to import the libraries in mongodb gridfs?

Tags: mongodb, go, go-modules

I am trying to work on MongoDB gridfs and I am new to it. I found online resources to make the gridfs work in golang and I found this [article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang--mongodb--a-quick-look-at-gridfs). When I took the code and tried to run it, it gave me the following error.

**Error**

```
could not import go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs (cannot find package "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs" in any of 
/usr/local/go/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs (from $GOROOT)
/home/bilal/go/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs (from $GOPATH))
```

**Libraries**

```
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
```

These four libraries have given me this error. But I gave just one error example.

Comment: Read and follow https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started on how to set up your project and use 3rd party libraries. Hint: Use modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you haven't installed the dependencies properly.

First you need to set up your project with `go mod init PROJECT-NAME` as described in the [referenced article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang-mongodb-starting-and-setup).

Then you need to install the dependencies as outlined [in the article you initially linked](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang--mongodb--a-quick-look-at-gridfs):

```
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs
```

Comment: I installed them but still giving me the errors.

Comment: Have you initialized your project using go mod init NAME as described in the [referenced article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang-mongodb-starting-and-setup)? Is `mongo-driver` referenced in your project's go.mod file?